# Array substring in deferred execution

Tags: c#, linq

Is there any way in LINQ to get a subset of an array in deferred execution (meaning copy at enumeration time, not build time)?

Comment: substring of an array.... huh?

Comment: I'm not sure, are you reffering to Skip(n).Take(m) ?

Comment: Can you show a small sample of what you want to do (pseudo-code is fine)?

Comment: @Gleno that will do, make it an answer

Comment: I do believe you are getting an answer in deferred execution.  (In this case skip 2 take 1).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, a simple way of taking a part of LINQ expression is `Skip(n).Take(m)`.

Comment: +1 for a good answer to a question that wasn't terribly clear.